# Using subprocess.run caused script to hang

Tags: python, subprocess, network-programming, python-3.7, python-3.11

First time asking a question here.

So I have been task to create a script that checks if a device is reachable via ping. Just liek to point out that I was able to create a working script on my laptop and was able to get our desired output. My laptop runs **Python 3.11.4.**

Now, we need to run all of our script in our scripting server(required by company policy). We have a dedicated scripting server. We mostly run our network automation in that linux scripting server. It uses **python 3.7.5.**

The issue is that, when I run the same script in the Linux scripting server, it hangs. No echo or whatsoever. Needed to press "CTRL+C" to stop it. When I did, it will return the below information:

```
**^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "ping_nodes.py", line 28, in <module>
    shell=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 490, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 951, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()**
```

After line-by-line isolation, the part where it actually hangs is the subprocess.run part, given below, where IP is a variable that contains our IP Addresses. I tried only using one IP Address but still the same behavior.

```
pingcheck = subprocess.run(["ping", "-n", "5", ip], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
```

When I add "Shell=True" it actually doesn't hang, BUT the result is different than what we want to see.

Is this something about the different python versions? Please if anyone our here has an idea, I'm open to anything.

Thank you!
-Newbie programmer

Tried adding a timeout=50 parameter, but it just showed an error "Command '['ping', '-n', '5', '8.8.4.4']' timed out after 50 seconds". But when I run it on my laptop, with or without the timeout paramaters, it worked flawlesly.

Isolated the part of the script where it hangs is in the subprocess.run part. No echo, need keyboardInterrupt to stop.

Tried adding Shell=True, and the she script didn't hang. Weird...
But the result we are parsing are different if the Shell is set to true. We prefer it to ba False.

Comment: Maybe your version of *ping* is different to mine. On my system, your parameters will induce a Usage error

Comment: If you're getting a 'usage error' you might work on a Unix-like system and need to change out "-n" with "-c". I assume, due to the "-n", that the reporter is working on Windows.

Comment: Hi @MichaelK and CtrlZ. I'm not having the usage or syntax error. The "-n" is actually working for both my windows laptop running python 3.11, and our Linux scripting server running python 3.7.5. I think the issue is more on the subprocess.run and why it hangs on the Linux server.

Comment: You've said you're running on Linux. The -n is OK. The problem is 5. What were you hoping that would do? See: [ping](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)

Comment: Note that the /n argument on Windows is equivalent to -c on Unix type systems

Comment: @CtrlZ The business needs is to send 5 ping packets to a device, hence the "5". Some of our devices are intermittent, and just 1 out of 5 successful ping is enough.

Second part of the script is to find the "TTL" string in the pingcheck output. Which works fine.

Comment: I think I need to mention that we run the python inside VENV, and -n instead of -c works

Comment: @whitemilkfish I refer you to the manual page for ping on Linux. -n is a standalone switch. It does not take any additional values. *ping -n 5 somehost* will induce an error on Linux. The /n switch on Windows does what you say

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your problem, all you're trying to achieve is determine if a given host can be ping'ed. If that's the case then:

```
from subprocess import run, DEVNULL, CalledProcessError
from platform import system

# if timeout is given it should be in seconds.
# it will be converted to milliseconds for Windows
def can_ping(host: str, count: int=5, timeout=None|int) -> bool:
    if system() == "Windows":
        c = "/n"
        t = "/w"
        m = 1_000
    else:
        c = "-c"
        t = "-t"
        m = 1
    args = [
        "ping",
        c,
        str(count)
    ]
    if timeout is not None and isinstance(timeout, int):
        args.extend([t, f"{timeout*m}"])
    args.append(host)

    try:
        run(args, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, check=True)
    except CalledProcessError:
        return False
    return True


print(can_ping("www.nonsense.corp", timeout=1))
print(can_ping("www.google.com"))
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
```